# To just show a point in the map, i need verify connection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary, connection

im just finish my first app and will submit it to the Apple Store. In the app i present a point in the map but always with the latitude and longitude. The question is: Do i need verify the user connection? If i dont do this my app will be rejected?

Comment: What do you mean by verify the connection?

Comment: I mean verify the internet connection, like use the Apple Reachability example. I read in some place that if i say in pinfo file that i use internet connection and my app dont use it it may be rejected. –

Answer (score 0):

If you mean whether or not you need to check for an active internet connection, you could just implement it to be safe. Here is a thread detailing the check:

[How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)